# Display array of objects without brackets, but elements, including comma's must stay

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, I am having a major brain fart.  I am trying to complete a test spec and the require output needs to look like so:

```
{"clojure": {"end": [10, 7], "start": [10, 1]}, "java": {"end": [11, 5], "start": [11, 2]}}
```

I have an array where I am dynamically adding objects.  Here is the code that fills the array:

```
function findHorizontal(word, grid){
let test = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < word.length; j++){
            if (grid[i].includes(word[j])){
                let row = grid.indexOf(grid[i]) + 1
                let firstLetter = grid[i].indexOf(word[j][0]) + 1
                let lastLetter = grid[i].lastIndexOf(word[j].split("")[word[j].split("").length - 1]) + 1
                    test.push({[word[j]]: {
                        start: [row, firstLetter],
                        end: [row, lastLetter]
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    return test
}
```

And here is what test looks like:

```
[{"clojure": {"end": [10, 7], "start": [10, 1]}}, {"java": {"end": [11, 5], "start": [11, 2]}}]
```

As you can see, the only difference between the above output and the test spec output are the brackets from the array.

I need to remove the brackets, display the objects and maintain the commas.  Looping through the test array just returns the last object, and if I try to retrieve the objects VIA another array or variable, I'll be in the same boat again?

What am I missing here?

EDIT:  Here are the exact test specs.

Comment: _"the only difference between the above output and the test spec output are the brackets from the array"_ - Nope... Expected: one object with multiple properties. Actual: Multiple objects with one property (wrapped in an array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an object as target.

```
let test = {};

// later inside of the inner loop
test[word[j]] = { start: [row, firstLetter], end: [row, lastLetter] };
```

Comment: Ugh, I tried something similar but didn't execute it as well.  Thanks a ton.  I won't forget that!

Comment: I was about to post the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the contents of the array as a string like this: `JSON.stringify(array)`, and then remove the opening and closing brackets. `Array.toString()` won't work because that won't print out the nested objects, so you need `JSON.stringify`.

However, if you can't be sure that the opening and closing brackets will be the first characters, and don't want to use regex, it could get messy.

You can do this with a reduce function which will accumulate the items in the array into a string, sans brackets:

```
const result = array.reduce((acc,crnt) => {
    return acc ? acc = `${acc},${JSON.stringify(crnt)}` : `${JSON.stringify(crnt)}`
},'');
```